# Take value from attribute using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

input.xml:

```
<comp>
  <link id="#c1-tbl-0001"/>
</comp>
```

output.xml:

```
<comp>
  <link newid="#c1-tbl-0001"/><tableno>1.1</tableno>
</comp>
```

i need the value for tableno from attribute value like 1 from tb1 and another 1 from 0001. so the ouput should be 1.1

i used the following xsl but it's not gives the exact result.

```
 <xsl:element name ="tableno">
  <xsl:value-of select ="substring(@id,7)"/>.<xsl:value-of select="substring(@id,12)"/>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: what is the given result then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the attribute you want to read is named `id`, not `href`. (Edit: You seem to have corrected this.)

You have to give a length to the first `substring` call, so that it only captures one digit:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(@id, 7, 1)"/>.<xsl:value-of select="substring(@id, 12)"/>
```

If the second number may use more than one of the digits, but you want to strip the zeros, you can do

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(@id, 7, 1)"/>.<xsl:value-of select="number(substring(@id, 9))"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your input. It looks like you got a letter l in "tbl", where you meant to put a digit 1, as in "tb1".

Any way, here is how you do it ...

If your input document is ...

```
<comp>
  <link id="#c1-tbl-0001"/>
</comp>
```

... then applying style-sheet ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/comp">
<comp>
  <link newid="#c1-tbl-0001"/>
  <tableno><xsl:value-of select="concat( substring(link/@id,7,1), '.')" />
           <xsl:number value="substring(link/@id,9)" /></tableno>
</comp>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... will produce ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<comp>
  <link newid="#c1-tbl-0001" />
  <tableno>1.1</tableno>
</comp>
```

An alternate template contents might be ...

```
<comp>
  <link newid="#c1-tbl-0001"/>
  <tableno><xsl:value-of select="
   concat( substring(link/@id,7,1), '.', number( substring(link/@id,9))" />
  </tableno>
</comp>
```

Using  is nicer because you gain fine control over formatting.

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution in case we only know that there are two numbers delimited by a string that contains a dash:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="link">
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "translate(concat(substring-before(@id, '-'),
                     '.',
                        substring-after(@id, '-')
                     ),
                            translate(concat(substring-before(@id, '-'),
                                             '.',
                                             substring-after(@id, '-')
                                             ),
                                       '.123456789',
                                       ''
                                       ),
                      ''
                      )
     "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<comp>
    <link id="#c1-tbl-0001"/>
</comp>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
1.1
```